# jQuery .hide() function "flashes"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the jQuery .hide() function in the head section of my page to hide a div on page load. The only problem is that it takes about .25 seconds before it executes the function, and when the page loads, it shows for that fraction of a second. It's enough to be relatively annoying. I don't want to use "display:none;" is css (for reasons I don't want to get into), but is there a way of preventing this? It's just a simple line of jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('div#mini-header').hide();
});
```

Comment: use `style="display:none"` in your html for this problem.

Comment: It's not a question of 'simple', you specifically asked it to run after the document is loaded and ready. Basically you're saying you want to wait but also you don't want your element to show up. There's no way these conflicting demands will resolve well. hide the element to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
<div id="mini-header" style="display:none"></div>
```

Your jQuery performs after `DOM` manipulate. That way this problem occurs.

You should do this with Html only to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will because, you have added the `hide` code in a dom ready handler, so till the dom ready event triggers the element will be displayed and then will be hidden when the code is executed.

The correct way to fix it will be use css, either inline or as a rule like you can use the id selector in css like `<div id="mini-header" class="hidden">`

```
#mini-header {
    display: none;
}
```

or add a css rule as below and add the class to the element like

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Would `DOMContentLoaded` make any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do it is the way you don't want to do it (by using css). Failing that you need to hide the element before document ready fires.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the initial visibility of the div to hidden.

```
<div id="mini-header" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('div#mini-header').hide(0);
});
```

I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

You should really do this in CSS. At least as suggested, add inline style to the element.

What your are using is jQuery to find the element and then hide it. That means that jQuery needs to be loaded and then your query select function will be run once the document is ready.

A 'workaround' is to add an inline javascript snippet just after your head element.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('#mini-header').style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

The correct way, as others are also saying, is to use CSS.